# Git username vs windows username capital

Tags: windows, git

I have a git repository set up on a linux server. I have a user with a username of cmcgrath on the git server. On our windows domain we have the same user cmcgrath. However, when he opens gitbash it shows his user as CMcGrath@computername.

This is causing major issues as he always has to run commands as a specific user instead of it pulling in the information automatically. We have checked his global settings and his username is all lower case.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: "This is causing major issues as he always has to run commands as a specific user instead of it pulling in the information automatically." - what do you mean by this? If it's just about `ssh` (or Git over ssh) reusing the current user's name as the default  when connecting to a remote server, that can be fixed by adding a `Host` entry to [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), or by adding the lowercase username to the remote path in the repo configuration.

Comment: Configure a username. See "Your Identity". http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup